# Why do files occasionally turn into read-only mode after saving in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a really strange problem with my Visual Studio.
I usually press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> pretty often (call me paranoid, well however I got that habit some years ago now and I really don't want to get rid of it :-))

Now I had the issue that I was editing one file, changing a few dozen of strings according to a spec I had open in Word; so I switch around these two tasks pretty often, make one or two changes and then save.

The odd thing is, **every once in a while, after saving, my file is suddenly in read-only-mode, so I cannot navigate through my changes** (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>/<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>) and have to reopen that file to continue to code and pray.
Indeed it feels random to me when this occurs:

sometimes I only change 1 thing and save and then it's immediately read-only,
well in other cases it will let me edit several things until it is stuck.

Someone else also experiencing this and maybe got a tip?
Maybe I hit some magic hotkey or something?

Comment: It happened to me... and I can't find any solution than just close-reopen the affected files. I didn't notice that this issue occurs after hitting several times CTRL+S...

Comment: Just to add some details, when it comes in the 'read only mode' you describe, it allows to type characters, but I can't type DEL or BACKSPACE, neither, CTRL+Z for undo...

Comment: [Possibly a bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/615270/file-becomes-completely-uneditable-read-only-in-certain-circumstances).

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo Then I suppose you got a different problem, when I have this issue I cannot type anything.

Comment: Could this problem caused by extensions? Check if you have changed key binds and accidentally press some key near `S`. Visual studio also have multiple-key shortcuts with delay, such as Ctrl + K then S.

Comment: Still a problem in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: I'll start trying the Ctrl-S to see if I see it. I use 2013 daily.   My recent issues with read only seemed to be disk integrity usually scandisk fixes it.

Comment: Are these files checked in to source control at all (specifically TFS)?

Comment: I'm using VS 2019 and this still happens occasionally, usually when I've performed a great deal of changes or refactoring. I've been unable to determine any cause. Any updates you care to share a few years later?

Answer (score 1):

My bad, please check if your projects folder is not a synchronized one, so when you edit (change) your project, the backup tool starts to update in remote location for synchronization purposes, so locks the file.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem is most likely that you are currently in Debug mode - i.e. the application is being run. Click "Stop" and it'll allow you to edit the files again.

By default, you cannot edit source files while the Debugger is running.

Comment: Not a debugging issue. OK, I did not explicitly mention this, but when I write that I am editing files and hitting CTRL + S frequently, I imply that this is working most of the time and workflow does not change (from my point of view)